# labeling in checkbox yii2 table header

Tags: checkbox, yii2

I have searching over web but cannot find appropriate solution.

what I to do is to give name or label checkbox colum in header.

by using this,

```
 ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',],
```

a column of checkbox will added to table.

what I do is :

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    'header' => Html::checkBox('selection_all', false, [
    'class' => 'select-on-check-all',
    'label' => 'Check Attend Only',
    ]),
    ],
```

and the checbox is appear at the left of "Check Attend Only".
in addition, the checkbox below the header are not centered.

How to position checkbox to the right of "Check Attend Only"? and centered checkbox below the header?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
        'checkboxOptions'=>['style'=>'display: block;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;'],//center checkboxes
        'header' => Html::checkBox('selection_all', false, [
          'class' => 'select-on-check-all pull-right',//pull right the checkbox
          'label' => '<span class="pull-left">Check Attend Only</span>',//pull left the label
        ]),
        ],
```

Because you can't specify the order of the label in the header, you have to position it using bootstrap classes

Comment: thank you @Pablo Flores.
your suggestion works fine :)